# How to have spotlight index .tex files?

Tags: spotlight, latex, indexing

I want spotlight to index my .tex files and show them as possible results when I search. I imagine the solution would work for any extension, but right now I only care about .tex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TexShop should ship with a Spotlight importer that does the job.

If not, you can try this homemade solution:

https://email.esm.psu.edu/pipermail/macosx-tex/2013-May/051009.html

Comment: Yes, it is included into MacTex, which I prefer to use.